# fatal: destination path '.' already exists and is not an empty directory

Tags: django, git, unix, digital-ocean

I'm getting this error when I try to `git clone` my Bitbucket repo from my remote Digital Ocean server. The server directory I'm trying to clone the repo into is not empty, as I'm setting up my Django project in it (`env`, `static`, `manage.py` etc are all in there). So how do I clone the repo into this directory that is not empty?

I've already tried a reccommended answer which said use `git fetch` and `git checkout -t origin/master -f` - and that didn't work - I got this error:

```
fatal: A branch named 'master' already exists
```

Any suggestions what I can do?

Comment: Did you follow these commands? `git init`
`git remote add origin PATH/TO/REPO`
`git fetch`
`git reset origin/master`
`git checkout -t origin/master` OR after the `git remote add ..` you could just say `git pull origin master`

Comment: Yes and still get the same error: `fatal: A branch named 'master' already exists`

Comment: Then run `git merge origin/master` to update your `master`. This might lead to some merge conflicts which will have to be resolved and comitted

Comment: I have already tried that and I get: `Already up-to-date.`

Comment: Does it show you that you are on master when you type in `git branch`?

Comment: Yes It says `master`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164034/discussion-between-laurynas-tamulevicius-and-zorgan).

Comment: why does the title state one error message and the body a completely different one?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand well, you have a folder in which you already have files that will be part of what you will clone.

What you can do is :

1. Initialize your folder as a GIT repository

   ```
   git init
   ```
2. Stash all your files in your folder

   ```
   git stash save -u
   ```
3. Add your remote repository URL

   ```
   git remote add myremotepository git@github.com:X/Y.git
   ```
4. Pull the stuff :)

   ```
   git pull myremoterepository master
   ```
5. Reapply the files you stashed

   ```
   git stash pop (or git stash apply if you want them to still be in the stash memory)
   ```

Answer (score -4):

Make sure the name of the project on your computer is different from the repo name. If they are the same, cloning will be impossible. E.g you could name your repo as **project_java** and the actual name of the project on your computer could be **project**